# one to one relationship with columns that are not id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have BudgetLine model. The model has budget_item_id column.

Second model is BudgetItem. it has an id and a column: full_name.

Now, I want to call: budget_line.item_name and get the name that is corresponding to the full_name in BudgetItem.

I tried (in BudgetLine):

```
has_one :item_name, :class_name => 'BudgetItem', :foreign_key => 'budget_item_id'
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your foreign key is in `BudgetLine` model, you should have `belongs_to` association in it:

```
belongs_to :item_name, class_name: 'BudgetItem', foreign_key: 'budget_item_id'
```

if you want to have method that returns only item_name, I'd advice renaming your association and adding separate method:

```
belongs_to :budget_item

def item_name
  budget_item.try(:full_name)
end
```

Comment: Same comment as for @krishna sahoo

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing in BudgetLine

```
has_one :item_name, :class_name => 'BudgetItem', :foreign_key => 'budget_item_id'
```

You should write

```
belongs_to :item_name, :class_name => 'BudgetItem', :foreign_key => 'budget_item_id'
```

Comment: But this gives me all the attributes. I want to get only "full_name". With your solution I need to do: budget_line.item_name.name. Is it possible to have the same result with only: budget_line.item_name